# Dash python dynamic

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard

I try to do a dashboard on python dash.
I succeeded the front-end. Indeed, I made appear a "year selector" but I do not understand how to change the graph depending on this year selector. Is anyone has idea or an explaination ? Thanks a lot.

````
#
# Imports
#

import plotly_express as px

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

#
# Data

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = dash.Dash(__name__) # (3)
    

 
    fig = px.bar(df2, x="dpe", y="Percentage", color="signature")  # (4)


    app.layout = html.Div(children=[

                            html.H1(children=f'Répartition des Leads DEC',
                                        style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': '#7FDBFF'}), # (5)
                            
                            html.Label('Year'),
                            dcc.Dropdown(
                            id="year-dropdown",
                            options=[
                            {'label': '2019', 'value': 2019},
                            {'label': '2020', 'value': 2020},
                            {'label': '2021', 'value': 2021},
                            {'label': '2022', 'value': 2022},
                            ],
                            value=2022,
                            ),

                           dcc.Graph(
                                id='graph1',
                                figure=fig
                            ), # (6)

                            html.Div(children=f'''
                                This a graph which show the repartition of the DPE
                            '''), # (7)

    ]
    )

    #
    # RUN APP
    #

    app.run_server(debug=False, port =4056) # (8)```
````

Comment: Have you looked at dash tutorials? You need a callback for the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callbacks for the selection of dropdowns to appear. Check out the [official documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callback to make you fig be interactive:

1. Change your dcc.Graph to: `dcc.Graph(id='graph1',figure={})`
2. Call back
   `@app.callback(Output('graph1', 'figure'),[Input('year-dropdown', 'value')]) def update_graph_1(year_dropdown): df2 = df2[(df2['Year'] == year_dropdown)] (# I dont see your dataframe so you will need to change this code) fig = px.bar(df2, x="dpe", y="Percentage", color="signature") return fig`